# Having dynamic tkinter label without StringVar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm pretty new to python and was trying to dynamically add buttons on to the GUI with its corresponding label on the frame, which works. However, I am having a problem afterwards when I click my button to open up a directory selector, the label does not update based on the new path because textvariable only takes in StringVar while I am using a dictionary to keep track of all the dynamically created buttons and its paths (which is not StringVar). Unless if there is some way to typecast normal strings to StringVar?

I hope I explained it well enough to understand.

Here's my horribly written code as I'm pretty much just trying to see how everything works. Basically, this program is supposed to take in a starting directory, and then  the other directories is where the starting directory will be copied to. I didn't get to the actual saving part though.

```
from tkinter import *

dirID = []
dirMap = {}
dirAmt = 0

def getDirName():
    dirName1.set(filedialog.askdirectory())

def getSaveDirName(event):

    dirMap[event.widget] = filedialog.askdirectory()

def strToStringVar(name):
    temp = StringVar()
    temp.set(name)
    return temp

def AddDir():
    global dirAmt
    global dirID


    b = Button(mainFrame, text = "Directory" + str(dirAmt))
    dirMap[b] = filedialog.askdirectory()
    b.bind("<Button-1>", getSaveDirName)
    b.place(x=10,y=(100+(60*dirAmt)))

    name = StringVar()
    name.set(dirMap[b])

    l = Label(mainFrame, textvariable = name)
    l.place(x=10,y=(130+(60*dirAmt)))
    dirID.append(b)
    dirAmt = dirAmt + 1
    update(self)

def save():
    for i in range (0,dirAmt):
        print (dirMap[dirID[i]])

root=Tk()
root.title("File Copier")


mainFrame = Frame(root, width = 600, height = 500)
mainFrame.pack()



#Variables
dirName1 = StringVar()



#GUI
GetDirLabel = Label(mainFrame, text="Directory to copy:")

GetDirButton = Button(mainFrame, text = "Select Directory", command = getDirName)#Button for choosing directory

DirGetPathLabel = Label(mainFrame, textvariable=dirName1)#Label for chosen directory

SaveToLabel = Label(mainFrame, text="Directories to copy to:")


AddDirbtnButton = Button(mainFrame, text = "Add more directories", command = AddDir)#Button for Adding directory

SaveButton = Button(mainFrame, text = "Save", command = save)



GetDirLabel.place(x = 0, y = 10)
GetDirButton.place(x = 100, y=8)

DirGetPathLabel.place(x = 5, y = 45)

SaveToLabel.place(x = 0, y = 70)
AddDirbtnButton.place(x = 130, y = 68)

SaveButton.place(x = 300, y = 68)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking what label is not updating? Also, there's no reason to use a `StringVar` here -- it's just another object to keep track of. You can get and set the text on the label widget just as easily as you can get and set the value of a `StringVar`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yea, I'm pretty bad at explaining things. Pretty much, I'm using StringVar because I need a label with text that dynamically changes. The only way that I currently know how to is to use textvariable, which only takes in StringVars. However, since I am dynamically creating the buttons+Labels itself, I can't set a unique StringVar for each created label.

Comment: You can change the text of a label with something like `l.configure(text="the new string")`